# How to add conditions for json model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Im trying to include an association but only ones based on its attribute's value

**Joo Model:**

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(include: [:foo, (:bar).where('bar.accepted = ?', true)])
end
```

> undefined method `where' for :bar:Symbol

Doing `super(include: [:foo, :bar])`, I have no control of what I want. How to accomplish what Im trying to do? Only include where `bar.accepted == true`

I was looking at [this](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) to see if it was possible. Im using Rails 5 API.

Edited to show associations:

**Joo:**

```
has_many  :bars, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :foo
```

**Foo:**

```
has_many  :bars, dependent: :destroy
```

**Bar:**

```
belongs_to  :foo
belongs_to  :joo
```

Comment: What is the relation between `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: @Pavan foo has many bars.

Comment: Ok On which model instance you are trying this?

Comment: In my controller, I have `render json: Joo.all.reverse`. So in the json object, Id see all the associations for `Joo`

Comment: Ok. What are the associations of `foo` and `bar` for `Joo`?

Comment: @Pavan see my edit for the associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [*doc*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) I see there *isn't way to include associations conditionally*. I think you can make a *conditional association* on model `Joo` and call it in `as_json`

```
Class Joo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo
  has_many :bars, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :accepted_bars, -> { where accepted: true }, class_name: "Bar"
end
```

Then you call it like

```
@joo = Joo.all.reverse
@joo.as_json(include: [:foo, :accepted_bars])
```

*Note:* Not tested!

Comment: Note: Tested! Result: WORKS!

Comment: @Sylar Glad to help :)